# CSS: Make Canvas as big as possible while keeping aspect ratio

Tags: css, html, canvas

I have a Canvas element that is inside a container div. When the user selects an image from his machine, this image should be displayed on the canvas. I want the canvas to be big as possible but at the same time keep the aspect ratio of the image. I know neither the proportions of the image nor the size of the container div, as this is relative to the screen/window size of the user.

If I set max-width and max-height to e.g 100% the canvas will not fill the container if the selected image is smaller then the container. If I set width and height instead of max-width and max-height the canvas doesn't keep the aspect ratio.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: By "big as possible" you mean have either the width or the height be the same as the container div's without the other one exceeding the container div's dimensions (I'm guessing based on the size of the window)?

Comment: Maybe you want to use JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So how would I do this with JS?

Comment: I'll post an answer... give me a sec

Comment: Also, do you want to show any code / attempts?

Comment: Haha, well, the project is a lot bigger, so I have to extract this specific part. But I will, if it helps you to find an answer. Also, I lied a little: It's not about an image but about a video; the user selects a video which will then be displayed on the canvas with certain filters applied to it. But that's all not relevant so I simplified it.

Comment: I finished it. It works. Check out the link to JSFiddle. Remember to accept if it helps!

Comment: If you want to resize a canvas element, don't use css, this will break the pixel ratio and antialiasing and make a lot of other usages (such as mouse events) a lot harder to make. Instead, you should set its `width` and `height` properties. `img.onload = function(){
 var max = img.width>img.height?'width':'height';
 var ratio = window['inner'+max.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + max.slice(1)]/img[max];
 canvas.width = img.width*ratio; 
 canvas.height = img.height*ratio; 
 ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
 }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're willing to use JQuery (or regular JavaScript), then a solution like this might work:

```
<script>

    // Note: this uses jQuery.
    // It makes getting/setting the dimensions easier,
    // but you can do this with normal JavaScript

    var img = $("#img");
    var container = $("#container");

    var width = img.width();
    var height = img.height();
    var maxWidth = container.width();
    var maxHeight = container.height();

    var ratio = maxWidth / width;
    if(height * ratio > maxHeight) {
        ratio = maxHeight / height;
    }
    img.width(width * ratio);
    img.height(height * ratio);

</script>
```

What this does is that it finds the ratio to multiply the width and the height by, whichever one is smaller (so that it will always fit in the window).

*Update:* Tested on JSFiddle.net. See it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jlam55555/k99q1sLe/2/).

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Yes, that seems like a smart way to do it. Thank you! So then I just have to add an event listener if the window is resized. Or would there be a way to use relative values (e.g in %) in the first place?

Comment: Like you said, the percentages may mess with aspect ratios or filling in the whole space. I think a resize listener would be easier (a single line to add in jQuery). Glad it helped!

Comment: I cant help but add a few suggestions to your answer. Invoking JQuery selector to crawl the DOM 6 times is not the best, when you only need it twice. I also think that as we are teaching inexperienced coders the use of conditional blocks without the `{ }` is demonstrating bad style. Your answer is correct just a little sloppy.

Comment: I would also add that OP was requesting for changing size of canvas element, which should not be done through CSS (jQuery's `width()` is CSS values).

Answer (score -1):

After reading your clarification about video, check out the following:

https://jsfiddle.net/d0dox9xt/

```
body {
    background: #eee;
}

#container {
    margin:0 2% 0 2%;
}

#v {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

The only trick is setting width:100%; This will maintain aspect ratio.

Note that in the JS

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var v = document.getElementById('v');
    var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
}

function draw(v) {
    c.drawImage(v, 0, 0);
}
```

The drawImage function can take many arguments. The first argument is inserting the media, the next two are for positioning. There are many arguments you can have to position and change the height and width. I left them alone so it will follow the CSS rules.

Here is a link to more on placing  in canvas: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Comment: What clarification about video?

Comment: @jlam55555 I wrote a comment to my original post. It doesn't matter I can adapt it.
@ brian-scramlin Thank you for your answer but I think this is not really what I meant. It's the canvas that I want to be displayed big, not the video. Furthermore, if the video is very high and I set the width to 100% it will overflow vertically. Still thank you for your answer.